# ranking date in R

Tags: r, ranking

I  have a dataframe of two columns TSH values and dates.
I want to give a rank number for each day (1 starting from the oldest date) as in the picture.

[image]

Comment: Please post data using `dput` and avoid using screen captures. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) about making a good reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

It is preferable to copy data using `dput` and not use images/screen captures.

Using your example data.frame, we'll call `df`, you can do the following.

Your first step can be to change your `DATE` to a date object. The code you provided in your comment can work, but if you use pipes such as `%>%` below, you won't need to make intermediate variables or objects. Instead, it will feed the result of one line of code into the next line. See [this](https://style.tidyverse.org/pipes.html) for more information.

Next, using `dplyr`, you can sort by `Date` (oldest first) and then use `dense_rank`.

To write your result to an Excel file, you can use `write.xlsx` from the `xlsx` package. There are other options available for this as well.

Here is a complete example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(xlsx)

df %>%
  mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATE, format = "%d.%m.%y")) %>%
  arrange(DATE) %>%
  mutate(ID = dense_rank(DATE)) %>%
  write.xlsx("filename.xlsx")
```

An alternative would be `cur_group_id` after grouping by `Date`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATE, format = "%d.%m.%y")) %>%
  arrange(DATE) %>%
  group_by(DATE) %>%
  mutate(ID = cur_group_id()) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  write.xlsx("filename.xlsx")
```

**Output**

```
  TSH       DATE ID
1 1.3 2015-01-05  1
2 0.9 2015-01-05  1
3 1.4 2015-01-05  1
4 1.6 2015-01-05  1
5 3.1 2015-02-24  2
6 1.6 2015-02-24  2
```

Comment: Thanks Ben ,it works after i did this acrobatic codes ( i'm novice in R) :    
    temp1=as.Date(data$DATE, format='%d.%m.%y')
    temp1
    A=as.data.frame(temp1)
    B=as.data.frame(data$TSH)
  library(dplyr)
    df=bind_cols(B,A)
    df %>%
      arrange(temp1) %>%
      group_by(temp1) %>%
      mutate(ID = cur_group_id()) '       dataframe is too long to past it by dput()  . However, how do i extract the table to excel? Thanks again

Comment: @MoKh  You don’t need to share all your data. Just try `dput(head(data))` to share first 6 rows. Copy and paste the result into your post above (edit your original question). Then, I can start with that, and will add how to export to excel too…

Comment: Thanks Ben, this is my dataframe : structure(list(TSH = c(1.3, 0.9, 1.4, 1.6, 3.1, 1.6), DATE = c("05.01.15", 
"05.01.15", "05.01.15", "05.01.15", "24.02.15", "24.02.15")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame"). How can i extract the table to excel or CSV file? thank you

Comment: @MoKh See edited answer, that uses your data, and writes to an Excel file. Good luck!

Comment: God bless you Dear Ben.

Comment: Hi again , it seems that day data are few , is it possible to rank by months?. Thanks again

Comment: You can use the `lubridate` library, and use `floor_date` which will reference the "first" of the month for any day in a given month. Your statement would look something like: `mutate(DATE = floor_date(as.Date(DATE, format = "%d.%m.%y"), unit = "months")) %>%` to use the first day of the month. If you need the original date, you can create a new column with the first of the date too, so you have both.